# Add and number blank line above each line in a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am using the following command to output a list of servers with associated IPs. For another part of my script, I need this output to be formatted in a particular manner. With an incrementing line number above each line. Example below

```
 paste <(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].Tags[*].{Name:Value}' --output text) \
         <(aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{PrivateIP:PrivateIpAddress}' --output text) | awk 'ORS="\n\n"' >> $TMP1
```

Which outputs ( in a tmp file ) :

```
Dev Server   111.11.11.11

Test Server     222.22.22.22
```

However how can I append numbers to each blank line like so?

Example

```
1
Dev Server   111.11.11.11
2
Test Server  222.22.22.22
```

Comment: Is it possible to get your output from a single query? I don't know what `aws` is, but some online docs have examples like ``Reservations[*].Instances[*].{Name:Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value, PrivateIP:PrivateIpAddress}``

Comment: aws ==  amazon web services command-line interface. I have been trying to use a single. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
$ cat FILE

Dev Server   111.11.11.11

Test Server     222.22.22.22   
$ awk '{ if ($0 ~ /^$/) { print ++counter } else { print $0 }}' FILE
1
Dev Server   111.11.11.11
2
Test Server     222.22.22.22
```

Comment: You seem to assume that there is an initial empty line in the data, and no empty line at the end. This is different from what's shown in the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda: yes, I guess this is what OP means

Answer (score 9):

If you change the way you create the file so that you don't insert blank lines (by removing your last `awk` step), then you can use the short `sed` script `=` to insert line numbers:

```
$ cat file
Dev Server   111.11.11.11
Test Server     222.22.22.22
```

```
$ sed '=' file
1
Dev Server   111.11.11.11
2
Test Server     222.22.22.22
```

The editing command `=` in `sed` outputs the current line number on a line of its own.  By default, `sed` outputs the contents of the editing buffer at the end of the editing script, before continuing with the next line. Since the editing buffer remains unchanged by the editing script, the data is reproduced as is.

Ideally, though, one would take the JSON document that I presume that your `aws` command could produce and pass that through `jq` to get the correct output, without the need to do two queries.

---

Working with the given data, using `awk`:

```
$ cat file
Dev Server   111.11.11.11

Test Server     222.22.22.22
```

```
$ awk '/./ { print ++c; print }' file
1
Dev Server   111.11.11.11
2
Test Server     222.22.22.22
```

If you need to have an empty line at the end, as in the question:

```
$ awk '/./ { print ++c; print } END { print }' file
1
Dev Server   111.11.11.11
2
Test Server     222.22.22.22
```

Both of these `awk` commands precedes each non-empty line with an incrementing counter, `c`, running from 1 onward.